# .Net WebBrowser control renders differently

Tags: c#, .net, webbrowser-control

I had a problem trying to use WebBrowser.
The problem is that the webpage is rendered differently compared to the view from IE11.

Through inspections and emulation in IE dev tools, it seems that WebBrowser is rendering the webpage as IE7, in which does not supports CSS3.

I had try to edit registry in

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MAIN\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION`

and set it to 11000. But the result is still the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently I should have set my application name as `myapp.vshost.exe` as well, since I'm running in via Visual studio.

For record, below is the key set in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MAIN\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION`

`myapp.exe` DWORD 11000

`myapp.vshost.exe` DWORD 11000